# Outlook 2010 GAL with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have the following code to get contacts out of Outlook from Excel:

```
Public Sub GetGAL()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.Items
Dim olContact As Outlook.ContactItem

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application.14")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items

For Each olContact In olFldr

Debug.Print olContact.FullName

Next olContact

End
End Sub
```

It is failing on this line saying there is a type mismatch:

```
For Each olContact In olFldr
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Also, how do I access the GAL as opposed to just my own contacts?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Here's my new code to access the addressEntry and ExchangeUser, however, not the country field yet:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetGAL()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olGAL As Outlook.addressEntries
Dim olAddressEntry As Outlook.addressEntry

Dim olUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser

Dim i As Long

'Dim sTemp As String

'Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application.14")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olGAL = olNs.addressLists("Global Address List").addressEntries

'On Error Resume Next

For i = 1 To olGAL.Count

Set olAddressEntry = olGAL.Item(i)

If olAddressEntry.DisplayType = olRemoteUser Then

Set olUser = olAddressEntry.GetExchangeUser

'Debug.Print olUser.Name & ";" & olUser.StateOrProvince
'Debug.Print sTemp

'ws.Cells(i, 1) = olUser.Name
'ws.Cells(i, 2) = olUser.StateOrProvince

End If

Next i

End

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks tigeravatar, that works great. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give this a try.  Although if you have tons and tons of entries in your GAL, it will take awhile to complete, and you may have to increase the 65000.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim appOL As Object
    Dim oGAL As Object
    Dim oContact As Object
    Dim oUser As Object
    Dim arrUsers(1 To 65000, 1 To 2) As String
    Dim UserIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set appOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oGAL = appOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries

    For i = 1 To oGAL.Count
        Set oContact = oGAL.Item(i)
        If oContact.AddressEntryUserType = 0 Then
            Set oUser = oContact.GetExchangeUser
            If Len(oUser.lastname) > 0 Then
                UserIndex = UserIndex + 1
                arrUsers(UserIndex, 1) = oUser.Name
                arrUsers(UserIndex, 2) = oUser.PrimarySMTPAddress
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    appOL.Quit

    If UserIndex > 0 Then
        Range("A2").Resize(UserIndex, UBound(arrUsers, 2)).Value = arrUsers
    End If

    Set appOL = Nothing
    Set oGAL = Nothing
    Set oContact = Nothing
    Set oUser = Nothing
    Erase arrUsers

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that you can only have `ContactItem` objects in the folder. It will break if you encounter an object of type `DistListItem`.

Declare the item variable as a generic Object, then check the `Class` property (exposed by all Outlook objects) or use `TypeName` function to figure out the exact item type.

EDIT: `PR_BUSINESS_ADDRESS_COUNTRY` DASL name is `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A26001F"`

For address entries you can see the DASS property names in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author). For example, you can click IMAPISession button, click QueryIdentity, select a property, look at the DASL edit box.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I use the name Type(Name) property?

Comment: Added a On Error Resume Next to the loop instead.

Comment: Don't just add "On Error Resume next" - ignoring an exception is not exactly the same as handling it. Plus you might have other errors (which you will now ignore). Use "If YourItem.Class = 40" or use "If TypeName(YourItem) = "ContactItem"". I meant Class property, not Type, sorry.

Comment: OK, thanks. When I open a contact entry in Outlook it has extra fields such as Country; how do I access these? Appreciate the help again.

Comment: You can either look at the Outlook type library and the ContactItem definition or use OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) to look at any live Outlook object and its data (click Item button). BusinessAddressCountry, HomeAddressPostalCode, MailingAddressCountry, OtherAddressCountry.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, didn't explain properly above: using tigeravatar's code above I'm exporting addressEntries from the GAL and not personal ContactItems, so how do I access the Country field in an address entry? Unfortunately, I'm unable to download OutlookSpy.

Comment: Use AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty to read the PR_BUSINESS_ADDRESS_COUNTRY property. the DASS property name is "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A26001F". Why can't you download OutlookSpy?

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow manges the DASL name (it assumes it is a link). See the updated reply above.

Comment: When I put in olAddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A26001F") I get a run-time error saying the property  cannot be parsed or has an invalid format. Am I doing something wrong? And I can't download OutlookSpy due to my company's draconian IT policy!

Comment: Do you have the http : / / prefix for the property name? See my updated answer.

Comment: Not sure how to get it? And when I look at the Locals window, GetProperty is not a property of PropertyAccessor; only Application, Class, Parent and Session are.

Comment: GetProperty is not a property, it is a method. What is your *exact* code that retrieves the property?