# How to handle null result of GetExchangeUserManager Excel VBA 2010

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm using code based off the sub at [Outlook 2010 GAL with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405567/outlook-2010-gal-with-excel-vba)

I would very much like to return the manager as well.

I've copied the AddressEntries.Item to a new list and looping through the list to return the manager name. So long as the Outlook item has a manager, it works fine. If not, it throws error 91. Can anyone help?

```
Set appOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oGAL = appOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries
For Each c In Range("b2:b2915")
    c.Select
    l = ActiveCell.Value
    Set oContact = oGAL.Item(l)
    Set oUser = oContact.GetExchangeUser
    'On Error Resume Next

    If Not IsNull(oUser.getexchangeusermanager) Then
        str = oUser.getexchangeusermanager 'object variable or with block variable not set
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = str
    End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use something like this:

```
Dim oManager As Outlook.ExchangeUser   

Set appOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oGAL = appOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries
For Each c In Range("b2:b2915")
    Set oContact = oGAL.Item(c.Value)
    Set oUser = oContact.GetExchangeUser
    'On Error Resume Next

    If Not oUser Is Nothing Then
       Set oManager = oUser.GetExchangeUserManager 
       If Not oManager Is Nothing Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = oManager.Name
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it and it hung as Outlook tried to contact the server every 15-30 names. I also noticed that the managers weren't accurate, unfortunately, no doubt because the item numbers have changed since yesterday. Seems like I won't get this to work for me.